# The probability that the second child of a couple whose older child is a boy is also a boy

Tags: probability

Someone is meeting a couple which has two children. One of the children, which is a boy, joins them. What is the probability that the OTHER child is also a boy if we know the OTHER child is younger.

I think the answer must be $\frac 12$. But what is wrong with the following:

Since we know one child is already a boy, the sample space, in order of birth, would be 
$A = \{ (boy,girl) , (boy,boy) , (girl,boy) \}$. And since we want the younger one to be a boy then the probability would be $\frac 13$.

Comment: Its okay to down vote ploblems, but it would be nice to leave a note or write a reason.

Comment: I would wish too one day SE would implement punishment for those who downvote without comments or with nonsense comments.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that the first element in the set is the older child: (girl,boy) will not exist

A={(boy,girl),(boy,boy)}

Hence, the answer is 1/2

Answer (score 0):

You can not consider

```
A={(boy,girl),(boy,boy),(girl,boy)}
```

because you already know that the elder child is a boy, so the chances for the second child also to be a boy is 1/2.

```
A={(boy,girl),(boy,boy)}
```

that is why

```
P(x)=1/2
```

x is the probability the other child is also a boy.

If the question did not consider about the boy being younger/elder then your answer is correct

Comment: What if we only know that **one of the kids** is a boy, not saying if he's older, younger or a twin. Does the probability change to 1/3m then?